# Prevent zoom in webpage like figma,

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a drag and drop app and i need to prevent users from zooming in and out of the web page ive treid things like

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

alse tried

```
 document.addEventListener("wheel", zoomShortcut); //add the event

  function zoomShortcut(e) {
    console.log(e);

    e.preventDefault(); //prevent zoom


  }
```

they all dont work.

Answer (score 1):

So here it is my problem is mainly on mac users, so I had to open some documentation and read about an event `gesturestart` this I think is mainly of mac books, so I made edits to my code and added this listener

```
  document.addEventListener("gesturestart", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    doStuff(e);
  });
```

And also added

```
  document.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    doStuff(e);
  });
```

And ran the code it worked for the safari but when I ran on chrome I got an error

```
Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation.
```

After doing some research I found out about something about setting the passive option in my event listeners so my code became

```
 document.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    doStuff(e);
  },{passive:false});
```

This fixed my issue I was able to prevent pinch-zooming on the entire web page by users like Figma

Comment: Tip: you can accept your own answer on stackoverflow, this might help someone in the future ;)